# Why are my updating iPhone apps "waiting..." forever?

Tags: iphone, ios

I've got an iPhone 4, not quite sure which version of iOS, but I keep current.

Recently, I got an update for one of the apps, started it, and then for some reason it got stuck on "Waiting..." indefinitely.  Another app later offered an upgrade, and when I accepted it got stuck on "Waiting...".  This has been a few days now, with both 3G and wireless available, with no change.

The apps don't have the "delete" button when I touch and hold on them, and I tried deleting them in iTunes but after syncing my iPhone there was no visible change.  (They're free apps, so deleting and reloading is a fine solution, but knowing how to kick-start the updater would be nice.)  The App Store app simply tells me they've been updated.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get that problem sometimes too on my iPhone 4, especially if I'm updating an app and I lose network coverage.

Here's what I'll usually do, either:

- Sync with iTunes
- Restart my phone by holding down the power and home buttons.

Either of those fixes the problem for me.

Comment: I think I beat you by a minute only because you went all fancy with formatting :D.

Comment: :-) I came here from StackOverflow, where they punish bad formatting with beatings. It's a hard habit to break!

Comment: SO is a bit of it's own world. Add to the fact that I'm not a programmer and it makes sense that I'm not nearly as active on it and haven't ingrained it's elitist ways into my habits :).

Comment: Does not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed in numerous threads in the Apple forums, but as of iOS 9.3.2, Apple do not yet seem to have fixed it. See this one for example:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7236083?tstart=0

Although rebooting your device *sometimes* fixes this problem, **be careful as it may also completely wipe the app from your device, including all data**.

Instead, the recommended way is simply to open the *App Store* app, visit the updates screen, and then stop and restart the update. I've had the update hang on me several times in a row, but it should eventually download and install.

I'm not sure, however, if this method is available for those with *Automatic App Updates* enabled, since I have mine set to manual.

Answer (score 1):

Reboot it. I've seen this problem a small handful of times on my, and one other individual's, iPhone.