# After iPad restore (from iCloud) apps still appear as 'waiting'

Tags: ipad, ios, icloud, backup, restore

I just got the new iPad, and since I backed up my old iPad using iCloud, I restored from the iCloud backup. After restore, it restarted and began downloading all the apps.

Now, I have all these apps on my Mac, so I plugged in the iPad at this point and clicked "Sync". The sync has not finished yet (it's still copying music), but iTunes has restored all of the apps first.
However, on the iPad all of the apps still appear as 'waiting' even though iTunes seems to have installed them.

Will this magically fix itself after sync, do I need to reboot, or is it more complicated?

#### EDIT

I gave up, and did a backup and restore via iTunes.

Comment: Were you on wifi?

Comment: Yes I was on Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same "waiting" problem as well.  I think what is happening is that lots of people are hitting the iCloud server at the same time on the "Happy New iPad" day and the system is slowing down.  I did a hard shutdown and then let it sit by itself - and then slowly but surely the apps started to resync. So sit back, grab a beverage of choice, and let the cloud do its thing (slowly).

Comment: Karim is right. Just let the iPad sit alone, by itself, while downloading and installing the apps. It will complete it over time. Patience. I ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and short [how-to guide](http://heresthethingblog.com/2011/10/18/restore-iphone-ipad-icloud-backup/).

They say:

> A final step involves re-downloading all your apps from the App Store,
>   a process that the iPhone/iPad handled automatically.

So my guess, your iPad and iTunes are clever enough to handle it by itself. When they notice an App is already installed, they wil leave it alone. If they find an uninstalled app, it will be installed.

Comment: I've seen that. My question is, if I leave it alone, will it go and download the apps again, or will it at some point realise that iTunes actually installed them?

Comment: See my edit above...

Comment: @NightLeopard I don't think that this will solve by itself. There have been similar questions as yours. This can go on for [several days](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/15865/13414). Simply rebooting the iDevice usually fixes this.

Comment: @gentmatt this can't be the intention of an iCloud backup... Should it be handles all automatically? Or is this a kind of bug in the iCloud story?

Comment: @Michiel I'm not sure how this is handled when restoring a device. I never had to do this manually. I've encountered this 'waiting' message in different circumstances.

Comment: @NightLeopard, I'll try this with my iPad (I happen to have to do it this weekend) and I'll let you know my findings!

Answer (score 0):

NightLeopard, iTunes does check version of app already (successfully i.e. 100% downloaded and) installed on an iOS device before iTunes attempts to re-download it.

Comment: The problem is, iTunes has already installed the app, but it appears on the device as 'Waiting'.

Comment: I know what you mean. I am in the same situation. After leaving the new iPad (what a name) to sync with iTunes, and with iCloud, I restarted the iPad and no more "Waiting" dimmed icons.

Comment: OK. My music is nearly finished syncing, so I should be able to reboot soon. (I don't want to interrupt the sync)

Comment: I left it to sync until the sync was completed. FYI (not that it matters I think), I've set my new iPad to NOT launch iTunes when connected, and I've also set the new iPad to backup to iCloud.

Comment: Reboot didn't help. I plugged back into iTunes and now it's syncing the apps all over again.

Comment: Guessing here: Could you stop the sync. Then uncheck the Sync checkbox which is on the Apps tab? Then start sync (to basically have iTunes complete syncing everything except the apps). Then when that's done, check the Sync checkbox on the Apps tab and let that runs its course?

Comment: That would destroy my entire homescreen layout, and probably app data as well. Looks like it's actually quicker to do it via iTunes all the way.

Comment: I know, Wish I know why this worked for me, and not for you. Weird. Sorry couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Found this post published 55 minutes ago. Hope this helps. http://t.co/oBPZpCSs

Answer (score 0):

Mine was stuck on waiting for over 8 hours. So, I just backed up my phone onto iTunes on my computer, then went into my phone's settings and deleted my iCloud account. Next time I connected to iTunes on my laptop, it couldn't sync via iCloud and had to just do it old school through iTunes. Everything downloaded just fine, and quickly.